# ThreeJS Vertex Drawing full triangle

Tags: three.js, 3d, geometry, mesh

have a question with regards with importing models into threejs: 
how do we build the mesh data?
has the mesh data got to do something with the draw mode of threejs?
is there a specific way to break down a geometry such that it is best built back up on threejs?

[image]

In the picture is the recompilation of the mesh, the mesh in green is the one I am looking to rebuild into threeJS, created in rhino.
The mesh in white is what has been created by rvta3c exporter and uploaded to threejs.
Is there a way to arrange the vertices such that I get a similar full bodied mesh on threeJS?

Anyone been through this before, am stuck and am looking for some light.

**edit 2**
Added some changes to the drawmode to find out the real problem as suggested by @TheJim01.
Also changed the mesh material so it can be easier to see the mesh.

**TrianglesDrawMode**
[image: TrianglesDrawMode]

**TriangleStripDrawMode**
[image: TriangleStripDrawMode]

**TriangleFanDrawMode**
[image: TriangleFanDrawMode]

Link to notepad containining vertex information
https://shrib.com/#ICkNCSwz51W9Ah.YWLLG

The next step for me is to probably understand Rhino better and deconstruct the mesh according to 3js draw mode standards.

Comment: The default draw mode for three.js is `THREE.TrianglesDrawMode`/`GL_TRIANGLES`. It looks like your model might have been exported using `THREE.TriangleStripDrawMode`/`GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP`. Either that, or the generated indexing is wrong or missing. I'm not familiar with Rhino nor rvta3c, so I can't really offer any more insight other than to examine your data to try to glean its format, and to set the appropriate draw mode.

Comment: Just a shot in the dark : have you tried to set the mesh's material side property to `side:THREE.DoubleSide` ?

Comment: @TheJim01 updated the original question to include the other draw modes and link to the vertex format.

Comment: @Hesha yes, the side determines the face of the mesh, this is double side as we can see both the back and the front of the mesh. It was single sided when i first loaded the model into threejs, it would only show the back half (split vertically) of the mesh when single sided